# Creating loop in Pandas DataFrame with conditional value in cell

Tags: python, function, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

In the script below, I assign the values 0 or 1 if the DataFrame cell has `No` or `Yes` in them.

```
answer= {'account': ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Tom', 'Isabel'],
     'a1': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
     'a2': ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
     'a3': ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
     'a4': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes']}
RPI = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(answer)
```

I'm trying to create a loop or a function for the RPI.loc statements below so I don't have to repeat the 50 columns that I have. Is there a way to do that?

```
RPI.loc[RPI['a1'] == 'No', 'a1'] = 0
RPI.loc[RPI['a1'] == 'Yes', 'a1'] = 1
RPI.loc[RPI['a2'] == 'No', 'a2'] = 0
RPI.loc[RPI['a2'] == 'Yes', 'a2'] = 1
RPI.loc[RPI['a3'] == 'No', 'a3'] = 0
RPI.loc[RPI['a3'] == 'Yes', 'a3'] = 1
RPI.loc[RPI['a4'] == 'No', 'a4'] = 0
RPI.loc[RPI['a4'] == 'Yes', 'a4'] = 1

    a1  a2  a3  a4  account
0   0   0   0   1   Adam
1   1   1   1   0   Ben
2   1   0   0   1   Tom
3   0   0   0   1   Isabel
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `dict`:

```
RPI = RPI.replace({'No':0, 'Yes':1})
print (RPI)
   a1  a2  a3  a4 account
0   0   0   0   1    Adam
1   1   1   1   0     Ben
2   1   0   0   1     Tom
3   0   0   0   1  Isabel
```

If need specify columns for replace by positions add [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (RPI.iloc[:, 0:4])
    a1   a2   a3   a4
0   No   No   No  Yes
1  Yes  Yes  Yes   No
2  Yes   No   No  Yes
3   No   No   No  Yes

RPI.iloc[:, 0:4] = RPI.iloc[:, 0:4].replace({'No':0, 'Yes':1})
print (RPI)
  a1 a2 a3 a4 account
0  0  0  0  1    Adam
1  1  1  1  0     Ben
2  1  0  0  1     Tom
3  0  0  0  1  Isabel
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked very well for me. I appreciate it very much.